# Using firebase auth to authenticate google cloud bigquery library - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, firebase-authentication, credentials

I'm trying to create an app where a user can perform queries on bigquery tables. However the NodeJS BigQuery library requires authentication using a `credentials` object.

How can I authenticate with bigquery using the same user that's logged in with `firebase.auth()`?

```js
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery')
const firebase = require('firebase')

const app = firebase.initializeApp(..);

await app.auth().signInWithPopup(..)

const bigQuery = new BigQuery({credentials: ???})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to use Firebase Authentication's to then access Google Cloud's other products, such as BigQuery. BigQuery requires an OAuth2 token, while Firebase uses JWTs. There is no way to convert the latter to the former.

If your users are signing in to Firebase with a social provider, they **may** be able to use the OAuth2 token from that provider to access BigQuery. But that is unrelated to their Firebase Authentication session in that case.

Comment: Do you know how to get the JWT from firebase? To your second point, what if I sign them in with the appropriate scope?

Comment: 1) The main Firebase JWR you'll be interesting is available with `user.getIDToken()`. 2) Yes, that would allow them access to BigQuery, but as said it has nothing to do with Firebase anymore at that point.

Comment: So how would you use the OAuth2 token obtained from firebase sign in order to authenticate bigquery?

Comment: @MatanTsuberi - Unless that identity has been added to Google Cloud IAM (which is a bad idea), the token would be useless with BigQuery. I recommend creating a service account that your code in Firebase manages which issues commands on the user's behalf with the service account providing the authorization to access BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks John, that is indeed the route to go if someone wants to integrate Big Query into their app. As repeatedly said, this has nothing to do with Firebase anymore though as there is no way to use a Firebase Authentication user to access Google Cloud's other products, such as BigQuery.